# VIM. Как удалить стрелочную функцию за одну команду?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, vim

Загуглив почему то все предлгают обычный способ когда просто выделяешь все через shift+v от начала до конца или приемом ma что очень не продуктивно. Есть ли способ удалить сразу всю функцию находясь в начале функции. Я знаю про d + numberOfLine + gg, но бывает не знаешь линию изза слишком длинной функции или просто лень бегать по неудобным клавишам фицр, почему то они мне не нравяться как расположены от 0-9 в ряд.

К примеру у меня есть функция

```
export const register = (name, email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_REGISTER_REQUEST,
    });
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };
    const { data } = await axios.post(
      "/api/users",
      { name, email, password },
      config
    );
    dispatch({ type: USER_REGISTER_REQUEST, payload: data });
    dispatch({ type: USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS, payload: data });
    localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(data));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_REGISTER_FAILURE,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
```

};

как удалить ее максимально эффективно? находясь в начале, в середине, или в конце функции. 3 способа. Спасибо!

Comment: хм... Для меня это редкий кейс, но когда подобное нужно я обычно использую folding: становлюсь на первую строку функции, сворачиваю ее и удаляю. Но наверняка есть и более удобный способ

Comment: принцепе такой вариант хорош, а не подскажите с помощью каких команд вы сварачиваете ее и потом удаляете?

Comment: @TANAQ Я пользуюсь zR(полное раскрытие)  zM (полное закрытие) zr (не полное раскрытие) zm (неполное закрытие)

Comment: Благодарю! Ответ нашел уже https://stackoverflow.com/a/11723259/14455320 в кратции dap и сразу удаляет параграм. Магия

Answer (score 1):

Ответ нашел тут - https://stackoverflow.com/a/11723259/14455320

В кратции опишу:

- Нужно взять на вооружение 2 простые команды

1. **dap** - delete all paragraph - удаляет полностью параграфф, будь то функция или что то еще, очень полезно
2. **da{** или **di{**. da{ - удаляет вместе со скобками. di{ - удаляет внутри скобок.